# How do we embed images in sphinx docs?

Tags: python-sphinx

I am quite new in using sphinx, Doing documentation for the first time for the python project.
How to embed image for example in the sphinx documentation ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use the `image` directive, for example:

```
.. image:: example.png
```

The path to the image is relative to the file. See the [Sphinx documentation](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#images) for more information.

Comment: Also I can recommend trying out the `.. figure::` directive, as it has some nice features.

Answer (score 93):

From the [documenation](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#images):

> There are two image directives: `image` and `figure`.
>
> An `image` is a simple picture.
>
> A `figure` consists of image data (including image options), an optional caption (a single paragraph), and an optional legend (arbitrary body elements). For page-based output media, figures might float to a different position if this helps the page layout.

Example for `image` usage:

```
.. image:: picture.jpg
   :width: 200px
   :height: 100px
   :scale: 50 %
   :alt: alternate text
   :align: right
```

Example for `figure` usage:

```
.. figure:: picture.png
   :scale: 50 %
   :alt: map to buried treasure

   This is the caption of the figure (a simple paragraph).
```

Answer (score 18):

In case anyone is looking to include an **inline** image, the following works:

```
The |biohazard| symbol must be used on containers used to dispose of medical waste.

.. |biohazard| image:: biohazard.png
```

(From https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#substitution-definitions)

Comment: Exactly what I was searching for, thank you! Once your image has been defined somewhere, the link (here `|biohazard|`) can be re-used inside the same documentation page easily.

Comment: Also putting multiple images in table cells becomes simpler, no more code-repetitions.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure there is a line between above the line that says .. image::

My image wasn't showing, but I just had to separate it from the text line that was above it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have to use a relative path, I created a `images` directory, in which case I needed to use the following for the image path:
`.. image:: ..\\images\\image.png`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).