# Including notebook with nbsphinx fails

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, python-sphinx, toctree

I am new to Sphinx and I want to write a documentation of a Python package. I have a problem when I want to include a demonstration file.

I want to include the file `demo.ipynb` using the extension `nbsphinx`. It is successfully installed on my computer. The extensions variable in my conf.py file for Sphinx contains the following lines:

```
extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.doctest',
    'sphinx.ext.coverage',
    'sphinx.ext.viewcode',
    'sphinx.ext.githubpages',
    'sphinx.ext.napoleon',
    'nbsphinx',
]
```

and the toctree in my index.rst is the following:

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 3
   :glob:

   demo
```

when I compile my documentation I always obtain the following warning:

> ```
> PATHTOPACKAGE/docs/source/index.rst:19: WARNING: toctree contains reference to document 'demo' that doesn't have a title: no link will be generated
> ```

Does Sphinx maybe try to include the file as .rst file? The `nbsphinx` documentation just says that I have to install the package, add `nbsphinx` to the extensions and that I will then be able to add my documents to the `toctree`. I didn't find any information related to this problem.

Comment: Toctree entries are supposed to be RST files (with a title/heading). https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-toctree

Comment: You can see a possible solution there:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25866102/how-do-we-embed-images-in-sphinx-docs

Answer (score 4):

I just ran in into this again and noticed that you need to make sure that your `source_suffix` config does **not** include `.ipynb`.
So the `conf.py` should look like this

```
extensions = [
    # ...,
    "nbsphinx"
]
source_suffix = [".rst", ".md"]
# note: do not add .ipynb when nbspinx is enabled, otherwise you get the "missing title" error
```

On top of that, you need to make sure that the notebook contains a title, as already pointed out in the answers above.

Answer (score 0):

Each notebook needs a title.

Just create a Markdown cell in your notebook with something like this in it:

```
# My Title
```

See also https://github.com/spatialaudio/nbsphinx/issues/310 and https://github.com/spatialaudio/nbsphinx/pull/401.

There is now a better warning, see https://github.com/spatialaudio/nbsphinx/pull/402.